# Syntax error when calling my stored procedure.

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, date, stored-procedures

Stored Procedure

```
create procedure insertUser
    @uname varchar(50),@udob date, @uadd varchar(100),@umob bigint
as
begin
    insert into userInfo values(@uname,@udob,@uadd,@umob)
end
go

insertUser 'Samuel' '1990-14-04' 'Shivajinagar Pune' 12345630
```

Error msg:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '1990-04-14'.
```

Comment: You separate parameters using commas when calling a stored procedure.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189260.aspx

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever... I have tried... but not working

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you... But I have got the solution... The problem was in my sql server... Somehow that stored procedure was not able to find my created table... so i deleted both table and stored procedure and created new one... and it worked... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to the SP is incorrect. Separate the parameters with `,` like below. Also, date should be entered in a standard format (mm-dd-yyyy or yyyy-mm-dd)

```
insertUser 'Samuel', '1990-04-14', 'Shivajinagar Pune', 12345630
```

Comment: and in sql server it accepts parameters without , also.

Comment: Did you try the `exec` keyword before the SP name in the above statement?

Comment: exec insertUser 'Nikhil Chaudhari','1990/14/04','Hudko Colony Lonavla',12345630

Comment: for above statement getting following error-   "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure insertUser, Line 0
Error converting data type varchar to date."

Comment: No... Actually I have tried to insert values into table without stored procedure... but not able to insert... it is giving an error near date only

Comment: I have tried with both the formats... but it is not accepting

Comment: "date should be entered in a standard format" - I agree. However, both of the formats you've shown *can* be problematic. The only format for "date only" that isn't subject to ambiguity is `yyyymmdd` (year, then month, the day, no separator characters)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever... yes... Firstly I have inserted in standard format only... then tried for another

Comment: @SujeetSinha Thank you... But I have got the solution... The problem was in my sql server... Somehow that stored procedure was not able to find my created table... so i deleted both table and stored procedure and created new one... and it worked... :)

Answer (score 0):

It would be clear when you pass parameter name = value while calling stored procedure.

Call like this,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertUser @uname VARCHAR(50)
    ,@udob DATE
    ,@uadd VARCHAR(100)
    ,@umob BIGINT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO userInfo
    VALUES (
        @uname
        ,@udob
        ,@uadd
        ,@umob
        )
END
GO

EXEC insertUser @uname = 'Samuel'
    ,@udob = '1990-14-04'
    ,@uadd = 'Shivajinagar Pune'
    ,@umob = 12345630
```